# Install R packages from linux command line

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I am using AWS EC2 (ubuntu 12.04) to run some simulations in R. I have a scripts that boots up the instance and updates and upgrades and installs r-base r-base-dev

I would like to add a command to the startup (bash) script that would install the doMC package. My instance is brand new each time I run the machine (**no R repos, no R library is defined**) and I would like to be able to install the doMC package right after installing r-base.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course -- `sudo apt-get install r-cran-domc`.  So install this just how you install R itself.

BTW `r-base` already implied `r-base-dev`.

Comment: Wicked sorcery this is!!! Does the r-cran-zzz work with any zzz packages from CRAN?

Comment: @ECII - I don't believe so.  Just look at the list synaptic gives when you search for r-base.  It's way too short to be all of the packages on CRAN.

Comment: @ECII:  Yes and no. We have well over 100 packages in Debian and Ubuntu proper; this was one of them. But there are add-ons: Michael Rutter's PPA for Ubuntu, and Don Armstrong's debian-r.debian.net (which seems to be down right now).  I have been involved with predecessor versions; google for these as well as for `cran2deb`.